# asp.net Returning Wrong Value with parameter

Tags: c#, mysql

So I Got a search return to work... however it's not finding the exact entry in the database...

```
MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(dbConnection);
                MySqlCommand cmd;
                con.Open();
                MySqlDataReader dbReader;
                string cmdText = "SELECT `BanID`, `GUID`, `BanTime`, `Reason`, `BanType`, `Proof` FROM `a3bans`.`bans` WHERE  `GUID` LIKE @pGUID";


                cmd = new MySqlCommand(cmdText, con);

                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pGUID", "%" + bans.GuidOrIP + "%");
```

When I search for *"e7af78997ef220a557c97a1a4c11e0c2"* which is a persons ID, it returns with *"fa32f7c456b368e17a278f3b165a550d"* which is a completely different persons ID.

If I change my query to `WHERE`GUID`= @prmGUID"` it returns as `null` value.

What am I doing wrong that it wont return the string I am looking for?

Comment: when you run this query into your db, what is the result ?

Comment: Both the `LIKE` and `=` searches in the DB query returns proper. But with the asp.net, it returns a completely different row.

Comment: e7af78997ef220a557c97a1a4c11e0c2 this is not proper guid-> this is how proper guid looks like :f03dec46-96df-4a3c-b109-aa97a3c75f49

Comment: it's a GUID for a game... that's how it is formatted

Comment: It might be helpful to see the schema for the table, how the GUIDs are created and also some sample data from said table? Perhaps there is some  trailing white-space on the GUID data or the algorithm that generates the GUIDs isn't sufficient and has caused collisions for multiple people / bans?

Comment: Also regarding your comments about returning null when using "=", I presume you also remove the "%" characters otherwise they won't be treated as wildcards and will be compared literally, thus yielding no rows as you most likely don't contain "%"s in your GUIDs?

Comment: The GUIDs are created via steam and Game client, nothing of which I have control over.  http://i.grab.la/06b01-cd892d8b-8a66-4b3b-b831-0503e7fa386d.png That is what the DB looks like, there is no "white space" i already got rid of that when I started this project a few days ago.  If I remove the wildcard, it returns as null.

Comment: What is the type and value of `bans.GuidOrIP`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It actually had nothing to do with this, lol I had 2 variables very similar and got them mixed up...

Thanks for the help guys

Answer (score 0):

```
MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(dbConnection);
 MySqlCommand cmd;
 con.Open();
 MySqlDataReader dbReader;
 string cmdText = "SELECT `BanID`, `GUID`, `BanTime`, `Reason`, `BanType`, `Proof` FROM `a3bans`.`bans` WHERE  `GUID` LIKE '%@pGUID%'";

cmd = new MySqlCommand(cmdText, con);
SqlParameter param  = new SqlParameter();
param.ParameterName = "@pGUID";
param.Value         = bans.GuidOrIP;
cmd.Parameters.Add(param);
```

by using this code it will look for same bans.pGUID in table and then return result.
try it.

Comment: Don't dump "fixed" code, explain what problem the OP has, and what changes you made to fix that problem.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "fixed code", I did explain the problem, and I did post what I was doing wrong.